# zoom every image displayed in a loop

Tags: php, image, zooming

im new in php programming, my problem is i want to zoom every image displayed in a while loop. here is my code..

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM room");
        while($display = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {

<tr>
      <td>   
       <div id="imageContainer"><!-- zoom id -->
      <div style="margin-left:15px;">

       <img width=120 height=70 class="thumbnail" src='<?php echo $display['image'];?>'> 

       </div>
       </div>
       </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What's your problem/error?

Comment: i have a gallery of hotel room images, each images is displayed by a loop from a database, now i want to add a zoom effect for each images displayed. i add a jquery (from my code the imageContainer is the id used) but when i run the scipt only the first image in the loop was zoomed. what i need to do???

Answer (score 0):

So you must put there some javascript or jquery (and more frameworks :D) code that will zoom on them,php cant zoom on image.
And there is a question how you want to zoom them.There are many possibilities to do that.You have miniatures of your pics and click on them make them somewhere bigger or how ? And I think that you have even the code what you placed here bad you are combining html a php.

Comment: I already used jquery the problem is when i run the scipt only the first image in the loop was zoomed. what i need to do???